# Linear Layout dynamically resize elements so everything fits on the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

So this is what my fragment looks like:

[image: screenshot of android studio]

Except that I have two textViews underneath my wheel image that aren't showing up. I would like both textviews to show up and have the RelativeLayout that is holding the images to scale it's height down to accomodate my textViews. The result should look something like this:

[image: screenshot of what I want android studio to look like]
(To take this screenshot I set an absolute height, which is not a solution).

I've tried various things including setting layout_weights, but that seems like I am assigning percentages to different elements, which isn't exactly what I want to do. I've also tried changing my base layout from linearlayout to relativeLayout, but I had the same problem.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Here is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.roberts.croberts.mantis.ShotWheelFragment"
android:id="@+id/shotWheelFragment"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#2b2b2b">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Simulate"
        android:id="@+id/simulateBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingRight="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Score"
            android:id="@+id/scoreTitle"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="00.0"
            android:id="@+id/scoreField"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageContainer">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/frame_back"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/frameBack"
        android:contentDescription="@string/backofimage"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/frame"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/backofimage"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:src="@drawable/reset"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/reset"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:src="@drawable/start"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:contentDescription="start"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#fff" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your LinearLayout at the root of this layout file places each child underneath the child above it. Whenever you declare heights to any of these children, the child is going to be that height. Period. Unless you allow for scaling of each of those children's heights, this layout is going to simply "go off the screen" of smaller screen devices. To demonstrate this, change your preview device to a Nexus 6 rather than a Nexus 4. I hypothesize that you will then see the entire layout, as you would prefer. Now, to avoid this issue on smaller devices, you have a couple of options:

1. Wrap this entire layout in a ScrollView (this probably isn't ideal and doesn't have a very good UX
2. Define heights for your ImageView (and other views that you've defined a height for) that will fit on the smallest device you intend your app to run on. This will still have problems for even shorter devices than you've planned for, but who really has one of those super short devices nowadays anyway...
3. (What I would recommend) Define the heights of each child of the root LinearLayout as weights and have the children of those children match_parent in their height attribute. That way, your entire layout will fit on one screen without scrolling, but in some cases, your views will appear to be more "squished."

I hope that helps, please let me know if there is anything I can clarify.

**EDIT: I've added the xml that should produce the desired layout using weights.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.roberts.croberts.mantis.ShotWheelFragment"
    android:id="@+id/shotWheelFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#2b2b2b">


    *****
    <!-- Change the layout_weight to your liking here -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight=1>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Simulate"
            android:id="@+id/simulateBtn"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:paddingRight="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Score"
                android:id="@+id/scoreTitle"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="#fff" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="00.0"
                android:id="@+id/scoreField"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    *****
    <!-- Change the layout_weight to your liking here -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageContainer"
        android:layout_weight="10">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/frame_back"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/frameBack"
            android:contentDescription="@string/backofimage"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/frame"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/backofimage"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:src="@drawable/reset"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/reset"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:src="@drawable/start"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:contentDescription="start"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    *****
    <!-- Change the layout_weight to your liking here -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/textViewContainer"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: "Whenever you declare heights to any of these children, the child is going to be that height" but I never declared any heights. Also, can you add how you would define the heights of each child as weights?

Comment: The children I was specifically talking about where your ImageViews within your RelativeLayout. You've given two of them a height and width of 110dp. You've also told one of them to `fill_parent` (you should use `match_parent` as `fill_parent` was deprecated)

Comment: Yeah, but I have the same problem even if I remove the two 110dp ImageViews, so I don't think that is the issue so much.

Comment: Sorry @ChaseRoberts, I couldn't edit that comment. That wasn't the only issue. The main issue is that the children of your main LinearLayout need to be weighted as I indicated in my edit to achieve the effect that you're looking for. Were you able to try those changes yet? Note that also grouped up your TextViews in their own container as well.